# Rename folder using `MoveFileA` with open file handles of the files inside

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a situation where I need to use `MoveFileA()` to rename a folder that contains some files with open file handles (in the same process).

It works if everything is done in the same thread, however, if those file handles were opened in another thread, then the rename operation will not work.

From what I can gather, Windows file handles are supposed to be shared across threads. So, why isn't this working?

I have a small test program that demonstrates my problem. It completes without errors if I compile and run it as-is. But, if I comment out this line:

`auto handles = create3Handles();`

and uncomment this line:

`auto handles = create3HandlesInThread();`

then `MoveFileA()` fails and the program prints out:

> Move folder failed (5)

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std::literals;

static auto constexpr ParentDir = "test-dir";
static auto constexpr ParentDirAfter = "renamed-dir";

std::array<HANDLE, 3U> create3Handles() {
    auto handles = std::array<HANDLE, 3U>{};
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < std::size(handles); ++i) {
        auto filepath = std::string{ParentDir} + '/' + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
        if (handles[i] = CreateFileA(filepath.c_str(),
                    GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                    nullptr,
                    CREATE_ALWAYS,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    nullptr); handles[i] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            std::cerr << "Create \"" << filepath << "\" failed (" << GetLastError() << ')' << std::endl;
        }

        if (BOOL ret = WriteFile(handles[i],
                    filepath.c_str(),
                    std::size(filepath) * sizeof(filepath[0]),
                    nullptr,
                    nullptr); ret == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Write \"" << filepath << "\" failed (" << GetLastError() << ')' << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return handles;
}

[[maybe_unused]] std::array<HANDLE, 3U> create3HandlesInThread() {
    auto handles = std::array<HANDLE, 3>{};

    auto t = std::thread{[&handles]() { handles = create3Handles(); }};
    t.join();

    return handles;
}

int main() {
    std::filesystem::remove_all({ ParentDir });
    std::filesystem::remove_all({ ParentDirAfter });

    if (BOOL ret = CreateDirectoryA(ParentDir, nullptr); !ret) {
        std::cerr << "Create parent folder failed" << GetLastError() << ')' << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    auto handles = create3Handles();
//    auto handles = create3HandlesInThread();

    if (BOOL ret = MoveFileA(ParentDir, ParentDirAfter); !ret) {
        std::cerr << "Move folder failed (" << GetLastError() << ')' << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto const &handle: handles) {
        if (BOOL ret = CloseHandle(handle); !ret) {
            std::cerr << "Close file handle failed (" << GetLastError() << ')' << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter who opened the file(s).  If they're open, they're open, and you are hosed.

Comment: @PaulSanders that's what I would expect also, but if that's the case, why does the program appear to work for OP, when the handles are created in the same thread?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I can't explain that, but I would invite the OP to double check his findings.

Comment: According to the Doc:[MoveFileA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefilea):The MoveFile function will move (rename) either a file or a directory (including its children) either in the same directory or across directories. The one caveat is that the MoveFile function will fail on directory moves when the destination is on a different volume.

Comment: Maybe races between threads. Try longer `Sleep` after `create3HandlesInThread`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply everyone. I could have sworn the test program was working before I posted this question... Looks like I goofed.

P.S. The Unix equivalent of this program works in both single-threaded and multi-threaded... Microsoft why??

Comment: Unix is much more tolerant performing operations on files which are open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out `MoveFileA()` shouldn't be able to rename the folder in both cases, and my test program demonstrated that.

I don't know what got to me or my PC because I could have sworn `create3Handles()` was working. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.